# How to get the Computer Description?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

**Hi All,**

How can I programatically get the Computer description?
I'm using C# and .NET 2.0.

[image]

I tried `Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostName());` but it echoes the `Full computer name` instead.

I also used the following code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem") ;
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection1 = query1.Get();

foreach( ManagementObject mo in queryCollection1 )
{
    Console.WriteLine(mo["Description"].ToString());
}
```

But this seems doesn't work, I got this exception:

`Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException was thrown in debuggee:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Do you have powershell installed?

Comment: Your second approach is correct, but the exception you're getting is odd. How did you add the reference to System.Management?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: by importing it `using System.Management;` I also added it in the reference of my project.

Comment: Import is one thing, but you also need to add a reference to it: Right click on the project root -> Add Reference -> .NET tab -> System.Management.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the registry value

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\srvcomment`

The simplest way to access it would be:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;  

string key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters";
string computerDescription = (string)Registry.GetValue(key, "srvcomment", null);
```

Comment: Please, please, please, _don't_ do this. This registry key is [technically documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787346(v=ws.10).aspx), but this is _not_ the supported way of querying this information. Use `NetServerGetInfo` with `SERVER_INFO_101` - this will be available via C/C++, Pinvoke, or JNI. In particular, some AV products lock the reg key, but the Net API continues to work.

Comment: @NicholasWilson NetServerGetInfo seems very involved to just query that, with structures and all PInvoke definitions.

Comment: What's involved about a structure? I admit PInvoke is going to be inconvenient (maybe there is a managed API after all?), but it's less a pain than having it not work when Windows 9 is released or something. Try this: remove all write permissions on the lanmanserver regkey, then update the server comment, and query it using the Net API. Clearly the reg key is being emulated for legacy applications and is no longer the primary place for the information.

Comment: @NicholasWilson answering your question: declaring it. I'm not arguing your points, I'm just saying there is a huge gap of practicality between this and the "ideal" solution. Please feel free to add your alternative as an answer with a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will obtain the computer description. I didn't test this on .NET 2.0, but the management classes used have been around since v1.1 so it should work.

```
        using System.Management;

        string description;

        using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem"))
        using (ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                if (mo.Properties["Description"] != null)
                {
                    description = mo.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: None of this is recognised by powershell.

Answer (score 1):

You need the DLL from the windows SDK
`System.Management.Automation.dll`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1187978/169714