# Running Powershell Workflow from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, workflow, powershell-workflow

I'm trying to run this code:

```
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        _outputCollection.DataAdded += outputCollection_DataAdded;
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"workflow test { Write-Warning 'this is a warning'; }; test");
        IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, _outputCollection);
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Windows PowerShell Workflow is not supported in a Windows PowerShe ll
>   x86-based console. Open a Windows PowerShell x64-based console, and
>   then try again.

How can I open a x64 based instance of Powershell from C#?

Comment: Is changing the target platform of your assembly to x86 an option?

Comment: no it's not unfortunately

Comment: Why are you asking something different than the title of your question? Please consider renaming your question to "How can I open a x64 based instance of Powershell from C#?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a work around that doesn't involve trying to use `RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace` (which is hard to use because getting the dll to work is [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186270/referencing-system-management-automation-dll-in-visual-studio/1187978#1187978))

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
//Create and open a runspace.
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    _outputCollection.DataAdded += outputCollection_DataAdded;
     PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"workflow test { Write-Warning 'this is a warning'; }; test");
     IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, _outputCollection);
}
runspace.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this? according to MSDN, PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode) method introduced in 'Windows PowerShell 3.0'. hope this will works.

```cs
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance =  PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) {
}
```

Comment: System.Management.Automation.RunspaceMode doesn't exist for me. The closest I can see is System.Management.Automation.RunspaceInvoke

Comment: @Backwards_Dave oh I saw your post below. then how about reference x64 assembly that stored in %PROGRAMFILES%? (which assembly is x64) 
sorry I can't give you a good solution :O