# Test ErrorRecord.CategoryInfo.Category in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm attempting to handle an error based on its `ErrorRecord.CategoryInfo.Category` enumeration value.

The code:

```
try {
    # assembly not installed on workstation
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Oracle.DataAccess')
    # throws error with a category of 'InvalidType'
    $connection = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($ConnectionString)
    $Connection.Open()

}
catch {
    # generates 'DEBUG: CategoryInfo.Category: InvalidType'
    write-debug "CategoryInfo.Category: $($_.CategoryInfo.Category)"

    # generates 'DEBUG: Category: InvalidType' (the `default` switch)
    switch ($_.CategoryInfo.Category) {
        [ErrorCategory.InvalidType] {Write-Debug "InvalidType"}
        [ErrorCategory.InvalidOperation] {Write-Debug "InvalidOperation"}
        default { write-Debug "Category: $($_.CategoryInfo.Category)" }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the code execute the `ErrorCategory.InvalidType` switch, instead of the `default` switch?

The accepted answer to [Referencing system.management.automation.dll in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186270/referencing-system-management-automation-dll-in-visual-studio) suggests that I need to install the `system.management.automation` assembly.

Is there a way to test the `$_.CategoryInfo.Category` without having to install this assembly?

Comment: I don't see how the linked question is related. `System.Management.Automation.dll` is the core of PowerShell. You only need to reference it to use PowerShell in C#/VbScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `[ErrorCategory.InvalidType]` isn't PowerShell syntax for using enums.

Either you could specify the enum-value (name) directly and let PowerShell convert it, or you could access the enum directly. Ex:

```
switch ($_.CategoryInfo.Category) {
    InvalidType {Write-Debug "InvalidType"}
    ([System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidOperation) {Write-Debug "InvalidOperation"}
    default { write-Debug "Category: $($_.CategoryInfo.Category)" }
}
```